# A calculation gets NaN but should be a real number

Tags: java

The following example takes a sum Integers as program arguments and calculates the average out of them. But somehow it prints "NaN"

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int sum= 0; 
    for(int i= 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        sum= sum + Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("Average: " + (float)sum / args.length);
}
```

How it could evaluate to `NaN`?

Comment: Sounds like `args` is empty.  Your code assumes otherwise.  When you step through this in a debugger, what happens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have tested your code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i= 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
        System.out.println("Average: " + (float)sum / args.length);
    }
}
```

I ran it as:

```
java Test 1 2 3
```

And the output was:

```
Sum: 6
Average: 2.0
```

Probably you forgot to pass arguments when running your java program? Because when I run it as:

```
java Test
```

I get:

```
Sum: 0
Average: NaN
```

Comment: I don't want to be that guy but how in the would so i add arguments in args? Im confused because I never initialized args?? so there is nowhere I can get the num. Can you be more clear? sorry again I'm learning java on my own so resources are very hard to come by... thank you again and happy thanks giving Frakcool!

Comment: @DanielAndrews Can you clarify your comment? I'm not sure I have understood well enough what you mean: Are you asking how is `args` being filled? Without initializing it?

Comment: Ok Frakcool, I totally understand whats going on. Im using eclipse so I ran it in terminal and added some numbers and I got my answer. Show I totally know what your talking about ty!

Comment: haha @Frankcool.. nah.. I totally understand now.. I really appreciate your help :) I had to add the arguments in terminal.. xD I feel dumb now..

Comment: Oh don't worry :) Good luck then ^^